# How to add shadow and round corners to a label in swift without using a UIView behind?

Tags: swift

I want to give round corners of my label and also wants to give the shadow of label but my shadow method and corner radius methods are not working together on label.

Here is my code with which I am working on my label

```
extension UILabel
{
    func ShadowLabel()  {

        self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 2
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 5, height: 5)

    }
}
extension UILabel
{
    func RoundCornerLabel() {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = frame.size.height/2
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        label.shadowLabel()
        label.RoundCornerLabel()
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly: you want to use UIButton extension to modify UILabel? In order to do that you should crate similar extension for UILabel

Comment: `viewDidLoad` does not guarantee the actual size of a subView.

Comment: For anyone googling here, the code example in the question, is absolutely incorrect

Answer (score 3):

What you're trying to do is not possible. Shadow is applied outside the bounds of the `UIView`, but the `cornerRadius` will not be visible without masking the `bounds` of the `UIView`. So, you will have to use a container `UIView`.

If you want write this in a generic fashion, write a `UIView` extension that returns a `UIView` that contains the view you want to apply a shadow for

Comment: Perfectly correct.  I did put in a solution if anyone really really wants to maintain the base class as UILabel!

Answer (score 1):

## One solution in iOS...

[image]

It's true that, bizarrely, you ***can NOT*** add background/shadow to a `UILabel`

If for whatever reason you truly want to **maintain the base class** as a UILabel, then one clean solution is:

is actually **add another UILabel on top**, and put the text in there:

(In the example, it's a simple fixed-width layout.)

```
import UIKit

class BettaLabel: UIILabel {
    
    override var text: String? {
        set { _overLabel.text = newValue }
        get { return _overLabel.text }
    }
    
    override func common() {
        super.common()
        addSubview(_overLabel)
        _overLabel.font = font
        _overLabel.textColor = textColor
        _overLabel.textAlignment = textAlignment
        text = ""
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        _overLabel.frame = bounds
    }
    
    lazy var _overLabel: UILabel = {
        let o = UILabel()
        o.backgroundColor = .clear
        return o
    }()
}
```

You can then do whatever you wish to the UILabel.

Of course, you then have the problem that,

it's just not that easy to add background and shadow to a UILabel :/

One solution:

```
class ExampleRoundShadowLabel: BettaLabel {
    
    override func common() {
        super.common()
        backgroundColor = .clear
        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize( width: 0, height: 2 )
        layer.shadowRadius = 2
        layer.shadowOpacity = 1
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        bg.frame = bounds
        bg.cornerRadius = bounds.width / 2
        
        layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(
          roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: bounds.width / 2).cgPath
    }
    
    lazy var bg: CALayer = {
        let l = CALayer()
        l.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        layer.insertSublayer(l, at: 0)
        return l
    }()
}
```

So if you really, really want to do it, that's one way.

[image]

The helper class for initialization is just

```
class UIILabel:  UILabel {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        common()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        common()
    }
    func common() {
    }
}
```

(Notice the extra "I" in `UIILabel` .. I for initialization.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is obvious. If you set **`masksToBounds`** to **`true`**, clips everything outside of the layer.

A shadow will be drawn outside of the layer, thus it is clipped, too. So, we cannot use the same layer for both of these effects I mean shadow and corners rounded so best solution is @Sparr comment.